# Why is the number of veriticies different from the number of corners?

Tags: geometry

http://infoshako.sk.tsukuba.ac.jp/~hachi/math/library/poincare_eng.html

[image]

I count 20 corners but the site says it has 16 verticies. Is there a math word for "corner"?

Comment: The statement about "16 vertices" refers to the triangulation given in `poincare.dat`, not to the dodecahedron above.

Answer (score 0):

The [dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron) indeed has 20 vertices. But that's not what the sentence you refer to is counting.

Gluing opposite faces of the together (which requires considerable amounts of high-dimensional bending) turns that dodecahedron into the [Poincaré homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere). And the resulting manifold can then be triangulated again using 16 vertices, with the combinatorics of the triangulation given in the file [poincare.dat](http://infoshako.sk.tsukuba.ac.jp/~hachi/math/library/poincare.dat).